# Why synthesized copy-assignment operator is defined as deleted if the class has a reference member?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ Primer, Fifth Edition, §13.1.6:

> The synthesized copy-assignment operator is defined as deleted if a member has a deleted or inaccessible copy-assignment operator, or if the class has a const or reference member.

The explanation from the chapter:

> Although we can assign a new value to a reference, doing so changes the value of the object to which the reference refers. If the copy-assignment operator were synthesized for such classes, the left-hand operand would continue to refer to the same object as it did before the assignment. It would not refer to the same object as the right-hand operand. Because this behavior *is unlikely to be desired*, the synthesized copy-assignment operator is defined as deleted if the class has a reference member.

Copying the class changes the object to which the reference member refers. Isn't this desired? Why the explanation say "*is unlikely to be desired*"?

Concretely,

```
class A {
public:
    A(int &n) : a(n) {}
private:
    int &a;
};

int main() {
    int n = 1;

    A a(n);

    /* Why is this allowed? */
    A b(a);

    /*
    Why is this not allowed?
    error C2280: 'A &A::operator =(const A &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
    */
    b = a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Copying the class changes the object to which the reference member refers."* -- I assume you are referring to copy-assigning here (since that's what your question is about) and not copy-constructring. If so, then you misread the explanation you quoted. It says precisely the opposite.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: That text you're complaining about is incredibly ambiguous.  Dropping back to pointer notation for a minute, `*p` is "the object to which the reference member refers to", and it *would* be changed.  So the statement is true, in the hypothetical where the defaulted assignment exists and acts element-wise.  But the reference is not changed to refer to a new object.  So the statement is false.  Alternatively, insert "the identity of the object" vs "the value of the object" to see the two conflicting interpretations of the same statement.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I've add some codes to the question. I still cannot figure out why copy-constructor is not defined as deleted but copy-assignment operator is in this situation.

Comment: @ChuyangLiu: Because reference can be initialized, needed for copy construction, but cannot be rebound, needed for copy assignment.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks, I understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reference can't be reassigned once it's created. That means it's *impossible* to make a proper assignment operator if the class contains a reference member.

A copy constructor is a different matter, because the reference *can* be assigned at object creation.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with "impossible". For example if your /intent/ was to make a shell representation the referenced object and assign the content of the one reference to the content of the other, then overloading operator = /could/ be the natural way to do it. But the default copy operator can't do that.

Comment: @GemTaylor you're free to define your copy semantics however you'd like when you write your own `operator=`. But the general expectation of *copy* is that the objects are indistinguishable after the copy, and the copy doesn't have side effects.

Comment: And I'd say that applies exactly in the pimpl model, where the implemented pimpl may be via a constructed reference, for example? I'm not disputing your answer, just the use of "impossible".